# How split inner array in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `array` of object. One object has an array inside.

```
var array = [{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third']}]
```

I need to have above array to be like this:

```
[
[{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third'], cSplit:'first'}],
[{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third'], cSplit:'second'}],
[{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third'], cSplit:'third'}]
]
```

I tried this code:

```
var array = [{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third']}]
var newArr = [];

for( var i=0; i<array[0]['c'].length; i++ ){
    var innerArr = array;
    innerArr[0]['cSplit'] = array[0]['c'][i];
    newArr.push(innerArr);
}

console.log('newArr', newArr)
```

But it shows:

```
[
[{a: "ai", b: "bi", c: ['first','second','third'] , cSplit: "third"}],
[{a: "ai", b: "bi", c: ['first','second','third'] , cSplit: "third"}],
[{a: "ai", b: "bi", c: ['first','second','third'] , cSplit: "third"}]
]
```

Why cSplit doesn't get the first and second value?

Comment: The problem is that you're mutating the same object, which is `array[0]`.

Comment: @Axnyff You are right. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = [{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third']}]

let newArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array[0]['c'].length; i++ ) {
    newArr.push({ ...array[0], cSplit: array[0].c[i] })
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```js
var array = [{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third']}]

let result = array[0].c.reduce((acc, current) => {
  return acc.concat({...array[0], csplit: current})
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It looks like you're using reduce to do a map.

Comment: I use reduce to create a completely new array instead of updating the existing one

Comment: map does not mutate either

Comment: `map` will return a new array of course, as the array on which the map should be perform is the value of `array[0].c` to have access to all the `value`. if You perform map on the value of `array` directly you'll have access to one item which is an Object and not `first, second and first`

Comment: `array[0].c.map(current => ({...array[0], csplit: current}) )`

Comment: there are many solution to this question, that's was the first way which was in my mind

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using `map`

```js
var array = [{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third']}]
   
var res = array.map((o)=>{return Object.values(o)[2].map(e => {
var newob = {...o}
newob.cSplit = e
  return newob
  })   
})
    console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be succinctly done with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const array = [{ a:'ai', b:'bi', c:['first','second','third']}]
const result = array[0].c.map(c => [{...array[0], cSplit: c}])
console.log(result)
```